# Publishing shiny app æøå UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, shiny, publish

When i try to publish my shiny app through

```
rsconnect::deployApp('path')
```

It works, but the website only displays the error:

```
ERROR: invalid multibyte string at '<c5>rstid'
```

I think its because the shapefile im using has the danish letter "Å" as a name in the shapefile@data. I tried

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")
```

to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Change the file name?

Comment: I could do that, but there is quite a lot to change, so if there is a fix it would be easier for me.